# Exception thrown whilst attempting to open program.fs in a f# solution built with MonoDevelop

Tags: f#, monodevelop

I have installed mono v2.4.2 on my Mac and added the f# language binding as an add-in from functional-variations.com/addin.

MonoDevelop throws an exception whenever I try to open the Program.fs file, the exception it throws is "...An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Fsharp.MonoDevelop.LanguageService."

The file is the default file created when building the solution. How do I fix the problem???

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the detailed information about the exception?

Anyway, it is currently recommended to use F# on Mono 2.8, which fixes several issues that were causing some F# programs not to work. I think this may be a reason for the error. You can also use Mono 2.10 (which comes with F# compiler), but then you need to do a few custom steps during the installation [as explained here](http://chrismarinos.com/f-on-ubuntu-linux-with-mono-and-monodevelop/).

Comment: Hi Tomas, almost there! Final stumbling block is the last step in the process, I am running /config.sh but cannot progress as it cannot find  mscorlib.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a error with the addin for MonoDevelop and MonoDevelop cannot handle it. You should ask the author of the addin for help. BTW the URL you posted is not valid.

Comment: The author of the addin is already on the case, just above :)